# Law of Total Expectation Estimation With Countably Infinite Support

Tags: expected-value

I am attempting to estimate $E[W] = E[E[W | A]] = \sum E[W | a] \Pr (a)$. I have expressions for both the conditional expectation and the probability of a, where the probability is Poisson distributed and the conditional expectation is calculated with a relatively expensive recursive formula.

As the Poisson distribution has countably infinite support (all non-negative integers) I cannot calculate all elements of the sum. As the conditional expectation has only a recursive formula (no closed form that I know) I cannot calculate an integral. The conditional expectation is also increasing in a. My thought would be to truncate, as the probabilities will be single peaked and decreasing quite quickly, but I was unsure as to if there is a guideline on where to truncate or if there is a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide more specific information about the conditional expectation function?  For instance, by knowing its actual rate of increase in $a$ one could predict the range of values of $a$ that contribute materially to $E[W].$  Without some such estimate you are going to be in trouble.

Comment: This is a queueing theory question, and it significantly depends on the ratio of arrival rate to departure rate. The actual recursive function is a little too long to fit in this context. In general, for reasonable inputs $E[W|a] \Pr(a)$ should be decreasing in a. Unfortunately, this is meant to also function as a tool for practitioners, so I may not always get reasonable inputs.